# Speed of a cycle wheel

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, everyday-life

Common sense tells me that the front wheel is going at the same speed as the back wheel, but somewhere, the phrase **100%  efficient** keeps nagging at my brain. That's because, I somehow feel that neglecting charging problems, a dynamo attached one wheel and a motor attached to the other will keep the cycle running indefinitely. (I think the argument is flawed, however)

Is there a *tiny* difference in the speeds of the wheels?

Comment: Why would there be? I mean sure, a real bicycle will flex and bend and that will effect the short-term velocities of the two wheels in different ways, but in the ideal case they come out equal on average. What are you wanting to know, and what does it have to do with efficiency?

Comment: I do not understand your question? What does efficiency have to do with bicycle speed? Please give more details.

Comment: I've edited it a bit

Comment: If they didn't have the same speed, one wheel would be skidding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're suggesting that you put a dynamo on the front wheel, so that you convert and store all the energy from that wheel. Then, you transfer that energy to the back wheel to power it. Now, the bike is moving, and you've got the front wheel spinning again, which means you can capture the energy and continue to power the back wheel. This obviously doesn't work because there's inefficiencies inherent in the system.

If you did have a "perfect" system with no friction, air resistance, etc., you could just push the bike once and let it roll forever. There's no need for all that dynamo perpetual motion nonsense.

At a very basic level, if your wheels were moving at different speeds, your bike frame would stretch out or compress, which just doesn't happen.

Comment: Well, except the inefficiency part and losses, the **ideal** power output from the front wheel will be equal to the **ideal** power used by the back wheel, right?
(Assuming that the dynamo is on the front and motor on the back)

Comment: Supposing the bike was off the ground, you could stop the spinning front wheel while capturing all the energy, and then use that energy to spin the back wheel up to the same speed.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Off-topic, but would this be practical ?(Legal does not enter into the picture)

Comment: Not at all practical, since it's not an ideal system. You can't actually capture all the energy, so you'd just end up spinning the back wheel slower than you started with. If it was practical, we'd all be zipping around on perpetual motion free energy bikes that you never have to pedal, charge, or fuel.

Answer (score 0):

The distance between the hubs of the two wheels is fixed by the frame, so the linear velocity of the two wheels must be the same.  There is no particular reason the diameters of the two wheels must be the same, so the rotational velocity of the two wheels.  Where does efficiency come in to this?

Added after edit to the question: If there were no losses in the motor/wiring you could apply as much power to one wheel as you take out of the other.  This would no more keep a bike going forever than not having the motor attached.  The net drive to the bike is zero, so the usual rolling/aero losses would still apply.  If you ignore those, a bike without a motor would also roll forever.  This still has no bearing on the relative speed of the wheels.

Comment: I just edited the question to make the efficiency part a bit more clearer